# Running same python code multiple times and getting inconsistent results

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python, so I am not sure if this problem is due to my inexperience or whether this is a glitch.

I am running this code multiple times on the same data (no random number generation) and getting different results. This has occurred with more than one variable so far, and obviously I cannot proceed with the analysis until I figure out which results are trustworthy. Here is a short sample of the results I have obtained after running the code four times. Why is there such a discrepancy between these outputs? I am puzzled and greatly appreciate your advice.

## Linear Regression

```
    from scipy.stats import linregress
    import scipy.stats
    from scipy.signal import welch
    import matplotlib
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.signal as signal

part_022_o = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Behavioral Data Processed\part_022_combined_other.xlsx')
        
distance_o = part_022_o["distance"]
        
fs = 200
        
f, Pwelch_spec = signal.welch(distance_o, fs=fs, window='hanning',nperseg=400, noverlap=200, scaling='density', average='mean')
        
log_f = np.log(f, where=f>0)
log_pwelch = np.log(Pwelch_spec, where=Pwelch_spec>0)
idx = np.isfinite(log_f) & np.isfinite(log_pwelch)          
polynomial_coefficients = np.polyfit(log_f[idx],log_pwelch[idx],1)
    print(polynomial_coefficients)

scipy.stats.linregress(log_f[idx], log_pwelch[idx])
```

## Results First Attempt

[ 0.00324568 -2.82962602]

## Results Second Attempt

[-2.70137164  6.97117509]

## Results Third Attempt

[-2.70137164  6.97117509]

## Results Fourth Attempt

[-2.28028005  5.53839502]

The same thing happens when I use scipy.stats.linregress().

Thank you,

Confused

Edit: full code added.
Also, the issue appears to be related to np.log(), since only the values of "log_f" array seem to be changing with the different outputs. It is hard to be certain that nothing else is changing (e.g. log_pwelch), but differences in output clearly correspond to differences in the first value of the "log_f" array.

Edit: I have narrowed the issue down to np.log(f, where=f>0). The first value in the f array is zero. According to the documentation of numpy log, "...Note that if an uninitialized out array is created via the default out=None, *locations within it where the condition is False will remain uninitialized*." Apparently this means that the value or variable is unpredictable and can vary from trial to trial, which is exactly what I am observing. Given my inexperience with Python, I am not sure what the best solution is (e.g. specifying the out-array in the log function, use a random seed, just note the regression coefficients whenever the value of zero is unchanged after log, etc.)

Comment: What is `distance_o?`

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that. This is a series consisting of approx 6000 data points that represent mouse cursor distance from a point on the screen over time.

Comment: Just curious, have you tried setting up various seeds?

Comment: And you're using the same dataset on every run? Not regathering the data every time?

Comment: @ Aditya, no I have never tried that before but I will take a look into it. 

@ Loocid, After obtaining the wonky first result that didn't make sense, I either selected and ran the code line by line, or just selected and re-ran everything all at once. Is this what you mean by "regathering"? The same variable was used, however. Edit: by variable, I mean 'distance_o'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a random seed to reproduce results. Do this with the following code at the top of your program:

`import numpy as np`
`np.random.seed(123)` or any number you want

see here for more info: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html

A random seed ensures you get repeatable results when some part of your program is generating numbers at random.

Try finding out what the functions (`np.polyfit(), np.log()`) are actually doing using documentation.

This is standard practice for scikit-learn and ML to use a seed value.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, it doesn't seem that these functions involve random number generation. Even if there is some part of the program generating random numbers, and I can achieve consistent results with a random seed, how do I know that my results are valid? For example, my first results in "first attempt" make zero sense and cannot be correct. With random seed, would this incorrect output be consistently returned?

Comment: it will help to see the full code to isolate what could be causing this unexpected behaviour

Comment: I added the rest of the code. I noticed that changes in output seem to correspond with changes to the very first value of my "log_f" array, so perhaps the issue is with np.log(). There don't appear to be changes to the "log_pwelch" array, but it is difficult to be certain because there are so many data points.

 I initially added the "where = f >0" argument when converting frequency array into log, because there were values of zero returning an error. This was not happening with the pwelch_spec array which further leads me to think the "log_f" array is the culprit.

Comment: as a general rule I would recommend printing the outputs of each variable and using len(), type() and shape() if it is a NumPy array. This will help you isolate what the program is doing and give you a better understanding of the data and how it interacts with your functions. In most cases the error is usually small but the process of finding it takes time. Inpsect your data and print as much as you can so you know yourself what is really going on. Also look up the documentation of pwelch compared to np.log. Some part of your program is randomised.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. You are right, there's definitely some part of the program that is randomized. I think I have narrowed the issue down to "np.log(f, where = f >0)." The first value of 'f' is zero, and when it "skips" over this, it is generating some random number. Sometimes this number is larger (e.g. -2.69), sometimes it is slightly greater than 0, and sometimes the 0 remains as 0. I can see the changes in the variable window as I re-run the np.log function to create/recreate log_f. Should I just accept the value when the 0 remains 0?

Comment: The length (201), shape (201,) and type (numpy.ndarray) do not change at all while this occurs